# What are the blue and white things on this Sunburst lichen?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, mycology

I am a amateur photographer I found some interesting things when I got home and looked at my photos. There are some blue/white cocoon. I  like structures on top of the sunburst lichen. I live in Colorado and took these photos on January 23. [image]
[image]

Comment: I have improved your title a bit but this is not sufficient. Please describe what you tried to capture in the photograph (name of the fungus), your geographical location and climatic conditions.

Comment: Are you telling about [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/730lx.png)? Adding pointing would help the question improve a lot. If you dont like to kill the artistic value of the photoes, then you may add [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUMJS.jpg) instead .

Comment: As well, the fungus is some sort of [Ascocarp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascocarp) of apothecial type of development

Comment: Hey thank you! and please excuse me for a minute I'm trying to figure all this out so I can be more specific in questions and examples. I'm very excited to be a part of this community thank you!

Comment: I had trouble doing this on my phone but I appreciate your time. I'll keep in eye out more of these because I can't find the good image of them on Google. So I might be able to upload some better images to the Internet.

Comment: The blue part you highlight are similar to the blue parts present more generally on other portions of the lichens, aren't they ?

Comment: There you go the top photo shows them a bit more clearly the color must be pretty close my phone automatically adjust colors a little bit. I'll be revisiting the area to find more of these I'll try to get better photos.

Comment: Lichen species looks like [*Xanthoria parietina*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanthoria_parietina)

Answer (score 1):

The small blue creatures coould possibly be (oribatid) mites.
I have them under my the binocular when I study lichen pretty often.
Their asociation with lichen is [well documented](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1096-3642.1984.tb02552.x/full)

Comment: A mite was my thought too. I had no idea of the order or anything though